# Is there a relatively cheap accelerometer that I can wirelessly connect to a raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

I’m interested in building a wristband that turns on a light when the wearer of the wristband makes a sharp movement. I am thinking of connecting a wireless accelerometer to a raspberry pi 3 that I own that would turn on a light when it senses the accelerometer move.

Is it possible to do this or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Rpi3/4 is a bit bulky and not that capable doing WiFi.  I guess ESP32 Wifi controller should be better, though still too big to make a wrist band - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwurH20jsvw

Comment: you could use a vibration sensor